# Right click to select a row in a Datagridview and show a menu to delete it

Tags: c#, select, datagridview, contextmenu, right-click

I have few columns in my DataGridView, and there is data in my rows. I saw few solutions in here, but I can not combine them!

Simply a way to right-click on a row, it will select the whole row and show a menu with an option to delete the row and when the option selected it will delete the row.

I made few attempts but none is working and it looks messy. What should I do?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Add more details where you having a problem. What you are trying to do, is not very difficult.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I finally solved it:

- In Visual Studio, create a ContextMenuStrip with an item called "DeleteRow"
- Then at the DataGridView link the ContextMenuStrip

Using the code below helped me getting it work.

```
this.MyDataGridView.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.MyDataGridView_MouseDown);
this.DeleteRow.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DeleteRow_Click);
```

Here is the cool part

```
private void MyDataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var hti = MyDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        MyDataGridView.ClearSelection();
        MyDataGridView.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
}

private void DeleteRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 rowToDelete = MyDataGridView.Rows.GetFirstRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
    MyDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(rowToDelete);
    MyDataGridView.ClearSelection();
}
```

Comment: Hi what control you use in DeleteRow_Click?

Comment: This answer does not seems to work when a `ContextMenuStripNeeded` event is present on the grid. Using `CellMouseDown` works.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! If you're using `AllowUserToAddRows`, you might want to check if `MyDataGridView.Rows[rowToDelete].IsNewRow` before doing the `RemoveAt()`, just in case the user has right clicked a new row.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I would suggest checking the hit type as well: if (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell) { ... } 

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittest(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I would add a "if (hti.RowIndex != -1)" check after setting hti, to care for user click on an empty area.

Answer (score 47):

For completness of this question, better to use a Grid event rather than mouse.

First Set your datagrid properties:

SelectionMode to FullRowSelect
and
RowTemplate / ContextMenuStrip to a context menu.

Create the CellMouseDown event:-

```
private void myDatagridView_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        int rowSelected = e.RowIndex;
        if (e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            this.myDatagridView.ClearSelection();
            this.myDatagridView.Rows[rowSelected].Selected = true;
        }
        // you now have the selected row with the context menu showing for the user to delete etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer works when a `ContextMenuStripNeeded` is present. The `MouseDown` based solutions does not.

Comment: @peter How to get the index of rows if multiple rows are selected ?

Comment: Hi vbp, I think you will need to raise a new question if not already answered, this question refers to selecting  only 1 row.

Answer (score 11):

```
private void dgvOferty_CellContextMenuStripNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellContextMenuStripNeededEventArgs e)
    {
        dgvOferty.ClearSelection();
        int rowSelected = e.RowIndex;
        if (e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            this.dgvOferty.Rows[rowSelected].Selected = true;
        }
        e.ContextMenuStrip = cmstrip;
    }
```

TADA :D. The easiest way period. For custom cells just modify a little.

Comment: Best method, also works when using keyboard only. However be warned: only works if a DataSource is attached. MSDN about DataGridView.CellContextMenuStripNeeded Event: "The CellContextMenuStripNeeded event occurs only when the DataGridView control DataSource property is set or its VirtualMode property is true."

Comment: What's the `cmstrip` variable referencing?

Comment: @reformed it's referencing the ContextMenuStrip that has been added from toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

It's much more easier to add only the event for mousedown:

```
private void MyDataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var hti = MyDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        MyDataGridView.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Selected = true;
        MyDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(rowToDelete);
        MyDataGridView.ClearSelection();
    }
}
```

This is easier. Of cource you have to init your mousedown-event as already mentioned with:

```
this.MyDataGridView.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.MyDataGridView_MouseDown);
```

in your constructor.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers posed in to this question are based on a mouse click event. You can also assign a `ContenxtMenuStrip` to your `DataGridview` and check if there is a row selected when the user *RightMouseButtons* on the `DataGridView` and decide whether you want to view the `ContenxtMenuStrip` or not. You can do so by setting the `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` value in the the [Opening event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.opening%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `ContextMenuStrip`

```
    private void MyContextMenuStrip_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //Only show ContextMenuStrip when there is 1 row selected.
        if (MyDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count != 1) e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

But if you have several context menu strips, with each containing different options, depending on the selection, I would go for a mouse-click-approach myself as well.

Answer (score 2):

base on @Data-Base answer it will not work until make selection mode FullRow

```
  MyDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

but if you need to make it work in CellSelect Mode

```
 MyDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;

 // for cell selection
 private void MyDataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
  if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
       var hit = MyDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
       MyDataGridView.ClearSelection();

       // cell selection
       MyDataGridView[hit.ColumnIndex,hit.RowIndex].Selected = true;
   }
}

private void DeleteRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int rowToDelete = MyDataGridView.Rows.GetFirstRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
   MyDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(rowToDelete);
   MyDataGridView.ClearSelection();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void MyDataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        MyDataGridView.ClearSelection();
        MyDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
}

private void DeleteRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 rowToDelete = MyrDataGridView.Rows.GetFirstRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
    MyDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(rowToDelete);
    MyDataGridView.ClearSelection();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContextMenuStripNeeded(object sender, 
DataGridViewCellContextMenuStripNeededEventArgs e)
{            
    if (e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
        e.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is work for me without any errors:

```
this.dataGridView2.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.MyDataGridView_MouseDown); 
this.dataGridView2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DeleteRow_Click);
```

And this

```
private void MyDataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var hti = dataGridView2.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        dataGridView2.ClearSelection();
        dataGridView2.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }

}


private void DeleteRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 rowToDelete = dataGridView2.Rows.GetFirstRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
    if (rowToDelete == -1) { }
    else 
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(rowToDelete);
        dataGridView2.ClearSelection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make this a little simpler by using the following inside the event code:

```
private void MyDataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{     
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)     
    {         
        rowToDelete = e.RowIndex;
        MyDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(rowToDelete);         
        MyDataGridView.ClearSelection();     
    } 
}
```

Comment: This would just delete the row with no warning or confirmation. I'm sure the OP doesn't want that.

Answer (score 0):

See here it can be done using the `DataGridView` `RowTemplate` property.

Note: This code isn't tested but I've used this method before.

```
// Create DataGridView
DataGridView gridView = new DataGridView();
gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
gridView.Columns.Add("Col", "Col");

// Create ContextMenu and set event
ContextMenuStrip cMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
ToolStripItem mItem = cMenu.Items.Add("Delete");
mItem.Click += (o, e) => { /* Do Something */ };           

// This makes all rows added to the datagridview use the same context menu
DataGridViewRow defaultRow = new DataGridViewRow();
defaultRow.ContextMenuStrip = cMenu;
```

And there you go, as easy as that!

Answer (score 0):

I have a new workaround to come in same result, but, with less code.
for Winforms... That's example is in portuguese
Follow up step by step

1. Create a contextMenuStrip in your form and create one item
2. Sign one event click (OnCancelarItem_Click) for this contextMenuStrip 
   [image]
3. Create a event 'UserDeletingRow' on gridview
   [image]
   and now... you've simulating on key press del from user

   > > you don't forget to enable delete on the gridview, right?!

[image]
[image]
and finally...
[image]