# how can i select a row in datagridview when i press right mouse button?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, contextmenustrip

i have a form1 in which my datagridview is located. my form2 has a textbox in which the value is taken from the datagridview of form1. i have inserted a contextmenustrip in my datagridview which will then take the data from the selected row and pass it on to form2. i have only done this in a listview. this is how i did it in listview

form1:

```
private void viewToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 strinf dis = listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[0].Text;
 int r = Convert.ToInt32(dis); 
 form2 nf2 = new form2(r);
 nf2.ShowDialog();
}
```

form 2:

```
public Form2(int g)
{            
 InitializeComponent();
 textBox1.text = g.ToString();                 
}
```

how can i do this in a datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is very well described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035511/1172862)

```
private void DataGridViewMouseDownHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var hti = dataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        dataGridView.ClearSelection();
        dataGridView.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
}

this.dataGridView.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.DataGridViewMouseDownHandler);
```