# Right Click to select a row in datagridview control in powershell

Tags: powershell, datagridview, wpf-controls

Im working on a project in Powershell the uses WPF controls.

I have a datagridview where only one full row can be selected. There is also a contextmenustrip that is working fine in the datagridview as well.

My problem is that I would like a right-click mouse event to select the row on which it was clicked and display the contextmenustrip. so there is no question for the user what they clicked. Currently, the selected row doesnt change on right click.

I've found many examples, but could use some guidance on converting them for use in powershell.

Once i get this down, i want to assign actions to each of the contextmenustrip selections
Thanks!

Comment: "I've found many examples, but could use some guidance on converting them for use in powershell." - what examples, and which parts are you stuck with?

Comment: For instance this is an example ive found thats not optimized for using in powershell 
(the first answer listed)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035144/right-click-to-select-a-row-in-a-datagridview-and-show-a-menu-to-delete-it

Im just not sure where and how to convert this. Is it in my contextmenustrip creation,, or in my datagridviewproperties, or both?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen,
So at this point I have a way of determining if it was a right click, and I think I have the way to select the row, but Im unsure of how to get the screen coordinates to populate my hittest variable...

`$DataGridView.add_mouseup({
    If ($_.Button -eq [System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Right){
        $point
        $HTI = $DataGridView.HitTest(?)
        $DataGridView.ClearSelection()
        $DataGridView.Rows[$HTI.RowIndex].Selected = $true
    }
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035144/right-click-to-select-a-row-in-a-datagridview-and-show-a-menu-to-delete-it), can be translated to PowerShell like as follows.

### Event handler registration

> ```
> this.MyDataGridView.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.MyDataGridView_MouseDown);
> this.DeleteRow.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DeleteRow_Click);
> ```

PowerShell doesn't support `+=` for event handler registration, but you have two other options. Either call the specially named methods that the C# ultimately converts `+=` to - they will all have the form `add_<EventName>`:

```
$dataGridView = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView]::new()
# ...
$dataGridView.add_MouseDown($dgvMouseHandler)
```

Alternatively, use the `Register-ObjectEvent` cmdlet to let PowerShell handle the registration for you:

```
Register-ObjectEvent $dataGridView -EventName MouseDown -Action $dgvMouseHandler
```

### Event arguments

> ```
> private void MyDataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
>     if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
>     {
>         var hti = MyDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
>         // ...
> ```

In order to consume the event handler arguments you can either declare the parameters defined by the [handler delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mouseeventhandler) in the script block:

```
$dgvMouseHandler = {
  param($sender,[System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs]$e)

  # now you can dereference `$e.X` like in the C# example
}
```

Or take advantage of the [`$EventArgs` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#eventargs):

```
$dgvMouseHandler = {
  # `$EventArgs.X` will also do
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Im still fuzzy as to where in the script all of this happens.  Does the argument go in the if statement for right click? Here's what ive got…

#Add a DataGridView
`$DataGridView.add_MouseDown($dgvMouseHandler)
If ($_.Button -eq [System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Right){
$dgvMouseHandler = {
param($sender,[System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs]$e)
 }
$HTI = $DataGridView.HitTest($e.x,$e.y)
$DataGridView.ClearSelection()
$DataGridView.Rows[$HTI.RowIndex].Selected = $true
}
$main_form.Controls.Add($DataGridView)
`

Comment: @Jimbaland The `if` statement would go _inside the `$dvgMouseHandler`_ block, so it'd be `if($e.Button -eq ...)`, assuming you've declared the parameters as `param($sender,[MouseEventArgs]$e)`

Comment: Placement of the If statement into the mouse handler block was the missing piece. Now working as intended. Ill vote this up once I get enough reputation points :)

Answer (score 0):

This post has good info but I’m still new to PS so it still took about a day to get it to work trying to put all the pieces together. Just in case someone else is trying to get it to work this is the code that worked for me.

```
$dataGridView.add_MouseDown( {param($sender,           [System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs]$e)
If ($e.Button -eq        [System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Right){
$HTI = $dataGridView.HitTest($e.x,$e.y) 
$dataGridView.ClearSelection()
$dataGridView.Rows[$HTI.RowIndex].Selected = $true } })
```